# Displaying scale on ArcGIS Engine map?

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine, wpf

I embedded ArcGIS Engine into a c#/wpf application and use it to display a map. 
Now for print my client needs to display the scale of the map like it is used on street maps (the small bar which shows how long 500m are, and/or the scale information like 1:25000).

Prints are always on a set paper size like A4.

Is there a simple way to achieve this in an ArcGIS Engine application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We made the layout in ArcMap and added a scalebar. In ArcGIS Engine we use the pagelayout to display a print preview and sent it to the printer. Not sure how this works in WPF but in winforms we used the sample for [synchronize map and pagelayout](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_synchronize_the_MapControl_and_PageLayoutControl/000100000153000000/) to get started, but customized so we could open different layouts.

Comment: I can't find a scalebar control in the ArcEngine documentation, any idea how it is called internally?

Comment: See scalebars: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Map_surrounds/00010000043m000000/

Comment: Yes, the AlternatingScaleBar is exactly what I am looking for - pity there is no clue how to add one to a AxMapControl (mostly I find the esri docs very confusing).

Comment: Oh, there actually is sample code "Add Map Surrounds" for the ScaleBar - which is one of the most convoluted and confusing examples I've ever seen. #Sigh